# Permission issue of generated folders in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Whenever we are doing the static content deploy in magento2 instance in ubuntu environment.the generated folders create with following permission

**0770** and so that when we are browsing via URL the page is not loading, I have tried in many ways of work for it , what magento2 freak guys doing for this kind of scenario rather giving the manual permission to the folder when it is created, the Following class is responsible for the creating the folders with permission.

This is default driver interface class

```
Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface

 const WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE = 0770;
```

This below class is used for the file generator

```
Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Io
```

This function is used for creating the directory

```
private function _makeDirectory($directory)
```

If you have any suggestions or idea post it now.

Answer (score 2):

We changed the way Magento sets file system permissions in 2.0.6. What version are you using?

We now do not set permissions on static files or anything else. For more information, see [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html).

Comment: Yeah we are using the magento2.0.5.

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is but you can at least experiment with 2.0.6 or later.